# Wordpress: current_page_item works for text transform, but not color

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on this little film's website, which I'm temporarily hosting at http://ivanfuentes.com/nolovelost/

After loosing my job in film, I decided to start working on my other passion, web pages... I've been learning a lot of html5 and css3, but still a newbie, as I discovered... my client asked me to build a Wordpress site, and I when found Atahualpa, I thought it would be a great idea to adopt it, so he can have lots of control over his site, with ease. Never again! From now on, I'll try to start as much from scratch as possible.

He wants to have the current page written in a different color on the side menu. For that, I used the current_page_item identifier from Wordpress, which actually did work, as I tried with different parameters, and, for example, did transform all the text to uppercase. But for some reason I still can't figure out, it does NOT change the text's color!

I checked the code using Chrome's "Inspect element" option, and as I can see, the browser did identify the item as "current_page_item", only it did not want to apply the specific color change (it's striked out).

Anyone know what could it be? I've been busting my braincells trying to figure this one out, to no success so far... any help, even just a hint at where to look for, with no further explanation, will be so, so appreciated, as this is all the work I now have. So also, if anyone wants to suggest any other ideas to stop being such a noob, I'll be glad to listen/read!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS tip:

The more specific the CSS, the more precedence it takes over existing CSS targeting the same items. Target the css like so:

```
.current_page_item a{color:/*YOUR COLOR HERE*/;}
```

If that is still being struck through, then make it more specific:

```
#DIV_ID #MENU_ID .current_page_item a{color:/*YOUR COLOR HERE*/;}
```

You can continue up the tree in that fashion adding more layers of specificity until it's the color you want, or you can do a manual override like so:

```
.current_page_item a{color:/*YOUR COLOR HERE*/ !important;}
```

That will ensure that your CSS won't be overridden, but I personally try and avoid using it unless absolutely necessary.